# pulling a value from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary, key-value

Here's my code for returning a unique value for identical keys in a dictionary. Right now, in my log, my "objects array:" is 6 (3 sets of (2 objects with identical keys)), and my "dictionary:" returns values for 1 object from each set (3 unique values). In my 'for' statement:

```
for (id key in dict)
{
       self.titlesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:dict];
       NSLog(@"titles: %@", self.titlesArray);
       self.titlesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[dict valueForKey:key] ,nil];
       NSLog(@"titles: %@", self.titlesArray);

}
```

The first log prints out the three unique values AND keys. The second prints only a single value for a single key (which is what I want.. but I need all three key values) So my problem now is that I am unable to pull a key for each unique value from the dictionary and add it to my titlesArray.

```
for (id key in dict) 
{
    self.titlesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:dict];
    self.titlesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[dict valueForKey:key] ,nil];
```

code isn't quite right.

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Images"];
    [query whereKey:@"recipientIds" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {

            // found messages!
            self.objectsArray = objects;

            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            for(id obj in self.objectsArray){
                PFObject *key = [obj valueForKey:@"titleLabel"];

                if(![dict objectForKey:key]){
                    [dict setValue:key forKey:[obj valueForKey:@"titleLabel"]];
                }
            }
            for (id key in dict) {
                self.titlesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:dict];
NSLog(@"titles: %@", self.titlesArray);
                self.titlesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[dict valueForKey:key] ,nil];
NSLog(@"titles: %@", self.titlesArray);
            } 
            NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", dict);
            NSLog(@"Objects array is %d", [self.objectsArray count]);

            [self.pickerView reloadComponent:0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I found to work. It takes the array and sorts through the keys to return only  unique values for a specific key:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Images"];
    [query whereKey:@"recipientIds" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            // found messages!
            self.objectsArray = objects;

            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            for(id obj in self.objectsArray){
                PFObject *key = [obj valueForKey:@"titleLabel"];

                if(![dict objectForKey:key]){
                    [dict setValue:key forKey:[obj valueForKey:@"titleLabel"]];
                }
            }
            for (id key in dict) {
                self.titlesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:dict];
                [self.titlesArray addObject:dict.allKeys];
                self.titlesArray = [self.titlesArray objectAtIndex:1];
            }
            NSLog(@"titles: %@", self.titlesArray);

            [self.pickerView reloadComponent:0];
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out, I finally realized that PFObject was not a class you wrote, but a library with documentation online. I probably would have made more useful comments for you if I'd realized that sooner...

Answer (score 1):

it looks like there is some type error in line

```
PFObject *key = [self.objectsArray valueForKey:@"titleLabel"];
```

it should be

```
 PFObject *key = [obj valueForKey:@"titleLabel"];
```

Comment: I think he is trying to pass what ever he gets back from this call `[self.objectsArray valueForKey:@"titleLabel"]` as key for the object in dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

How does your PFObject look like. Does it have strings in it?. According to your question you already know that you can't pass a PFObject as key for dictionary. If your object is some what like this

```
interface PFObject : NSObject

{
    NSString *keyString;
    ......
    .Some other variables
}
```

Then you should be using it like this to set it as key

```
PFObject *key = [self.objectsArray valueForKey:@"titleLabel"];

            if(![dict objectForKey:@"titleLabel"]){
                [dict setValue:obj forKey:[key valueForKey@"titleLabel"]];
            }
```

Comment: I updated my question to show PFObject definition. I tried using the dot notation to access the property but it throws an error of property not found. Parse is storing the key as a string so I don't understand why I can't access it as such

Comment: thanks! it didn't solve the problem but helped me look at it differently to where I was able to get a little further a long with it. Still stuck though.

Comment: Okay, can you update your question showing where you are got stuck.

Comment: I actually just got it, Though I still need to analyze it figure out exactly what's going on. But the code I posted returns only unique values for given keys. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's happening in this line, isn't it:

```
 if(![dict objectForKey:@"titleLabel"]){
            [dict setValue:obj forKey:key];
        }
    }
```

You are setting "obj" as a value, no problem there, but then you are using "key" which is a PFObject, but NSDictionary requires a NSString for the key.

If PFObject contains a NSString property that you want to use, you can pass that in. For example, if PFObject has an NSString property called "name" you could call this:

```
if(![dict objectForKey:@"titleLabel"]) {
           [dict setValue:obj forKey:key.name];
        }
    }
```

The relevant thing to notice is the types of the parameters when NSMutableDictionary defines this method, namely the (NSString*):

```
 - (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
```

Comment: I updated my question to show the definition of the PFObject and keys. What you said makes sense to me as far as accessing the string property though I tried using dot notation to access it but an error says property not found. It's being saved to the backend(Parse) as a string because I've checked.. so I'm not understanding why I can't access it as such.

Comment: If PFObject is a subclass of NSMutableDictionary, then you'll need to do the full [image objectForKey:somekey], assuming the object returned is a NSString, then you can pass that string in as the key in your [dict setValue:obj forKey:] statement.   Dot accessor notation works with properties of objects, not key/object pairs of a dictionary.

Comment: Gotcha. Well I've been working on it a bit and have made some progress. I've updated my original question and code to reflect my current state. I am able to get a single unique value for a key now but am still having trouble getting a unique value for each of the keys in my dictionary.